# PVC Pipe Venting air outside

Tags: pipe, vent, pvc

Why does hot air vent outside when heater isn't on? I understand it venting hot air out when heater is on but I don't know why it vents air when heater isn't on.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Is this a water heater or HVAC heater? Is it always venting hot air when the heater isn't running, or just sometimes?

Comment: @mmathis don't know if it's from water heater or furnace. Can it be from heater if heater not running.

Comment: It only runs infrequently. Only for about 2-3 mins. Not often.